# Invoke Matlab `loadobj` when input is an object, *before* it becomes a `struct`

Tags: matlab, oop

My initial foray into `loadobj`: I found the a [code pattern and explanation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/flexible-saveobj-and-loadobj-pattern.html#buz53zs-3):

> If the `load` function encounters an error, `load` passes `loadobj` a `struct` instead of an object

My load errors come from setters that use properties that haven't yet
been assigned to in the load process.  I want to define a `loadobj`
method that avoids said errors and avoids copying from a `struct`
altogether.  I do that by setting the properties in the order that
they are meant to be set. Using the code pattern from the above
webpage:

```
methods(Static)

   function oOut = loadobj(oIn)

      if isstruct( oIn ) % Diagnostic breakpoint set here
         error('Load failed');
      end % if

      % Example code pattern shows input object assigned to output
      % object, but I want to control the order in which
      % properties are assigned to

      oOut.TstepPrYr = oIn.TstepPrYr;
      oOut.TwinYrs = oIn.TwinYrs;
      oOut.Twin1sidePadYrs = oIn.Twin1sidePadYrs;

      % The following properties should have been set by setters
      %     TwinPaddedYrs
      %     TwinPaddedDays
      %     TstepDays
      %     TwinPaddedTsteps % Not used

      % There are also many other properties.  With the key
      % properties set, I should now be able to copy the rest in
      % one shot.

      oOut = oIn;

   end % function

end % methods(Static)
```

Right at the top, I trap the case where the input argument is a `struct`.
Such a condition would
mean that load failed with when input argument was a bonafide object.
I shouldn't continue in that case -- I should fix the `loadobj` code instead.

Since `loadobj` assigns values to properties in the right order, it
should never fail, and hence, it should never be called again with a
`struct` argument.  Unfortunately, I'm still erroring out in a setter
due to non-existent property values.  I put in a breakpoint at the top
of `loadobj` to see if the input argument is indeed a `struct` -- it is!
So `loadobj` probably isn't even being called with a bonafide object.
I conjecture that Matlab's default loading code (and load ordering) is
being used instead.  According to the top of the [`loadobj`
help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html), this is
not what I should expect.

Can someone please suggest what I can do to further troubleshoot this?
In case it matters, my class is derived from `matlab.mixin.Copyable`.

Odd behaviour observed: If I use the debugger to continue right into the above `error` statement, it generates a Matlab warning instead of an error.  But it still exits.

Comment: Did you implement `saveobj`? `load` builds your object, then calls `loadobj`. If building the object fails, it calls `loadobj` with a struct. In your case, building the object initially fails. Define a `saveobj` that outputs a struct with those three fields.

Comment: I haven't implemented a `saveobj`, but from what I read, it shouldn't be necessary in order to use `loadobj`. In the interest of avoiding extraneous code, I am just trying to implement `loadobj`, which (apparently) can be done, and isn't necessarily even discouraged. I thought that the issue here is just understanding how `loadobj` works. Does it get called with an object first, and re-called if that fails? The fact that the example pattern contains `if isstruct...` seems to imply exactly that, and the `loadobj` help also seems to imply that.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it does exactly that. But if it calls your function with an object of your class, it has already constructed it. Why do you need to re-construct it then? What is the point of this `loadobj`? Given that your objects cannot build without the `loadobj`, you'll have to make it so that a struct is passed to `loadobj`. And you do that by defining a `saveobj`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to move the line `oOut = oIn;` to *before* you start initializing properties. The variable `oOut` isn't initialized to an object by default; it is initialized to a structure when you start assigning properties with dot notation. Alternatively, you could initialize `oOut` with a call to the constructor, then move properties from `oIn`.

Having the line `oOut = oIn;` at the end of the `loadobj` method simply sets `oOut` to the unaltered `oIn` object that was passed, without any modifications.

Comment: Darn. Your lat sentence is so obvious in retrospect. But I'm confused by the preceding paragraph. My understanding of `loadobj` is `load` first calls it with the saved object as the input, and if it fails, it is called again with a `structs` version of the object. Is this not correct?  In any case, I have encountered a mystery: I no longer experience the error. I tried all combinations of `clear all`, `clear functions`, `clear classes`, and rebooting Matlab to recreate the conditions.

Comment: While the above sounds like a good thing, it's actually very bad, It means that a known problem can't be produced, so I can't troubleshoot. It will rear its head when I can least afford the detour.  I know it will, because the cause is known and I haven't fixed it.  :(

Comment: @user36800: This is how I believe the process works: `load` attempts to load the object data and construct the object. If it succeeds, that object is passed to any existing `loadobj` method for any additional setup (i.e. regenerating a file ID, etc.). If the loading and object construction fails, or if the object has been saved as a structure by a `saveobj` routine, the structure of object data is passed to `loadobj` so that it can attempt to construct an object itself.

Comment: @user36800: As for your problem recreating the error, it's possible you modified the class definition but didn't clear the old class objects from the workspace, leading to some undefined behavior. If it's working properly now after clearing the workspace, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the take on `loadobj` workings.  I'm going to suggest that TMW be more explicit in the doc page. As for modifying the class, I take snap shots of the entire project regularly, and can diff the current code base with previous snapshots.  I can't find any code differences (which are all formatting and commenting) that would explain the disappearance of the problem symptoms.  My concern is more about the inability to troubleshoot, as I am now at the mercy of the timing with which the problem decides to recur.  Ah well, welcome to...reality, I guess.